# Multiple <cc:insertChildren /> in the same composite component

Tags: autocomplete, jsf-2, datatable, primefaces, composite-component

I'm trying to do a composite component with union of a autoComplete and a dataTable. Like this:

```
<util:myCustomComp ...>
    <p:column>#{item.code}</p:column>
    <p:column>#{item.name}</p:column>
</util:myCustomComp>
```

And in CC file:

```
<p:autoComplete ...>
    <cc:insertChildren /> <!-- Show columns only in autocomplete -->
</p:autoComplete>
<p:dataTable ...>
    <cc:insertChildren />
</p:dataTable>
```

But the second  isnt rendered, render only the first and skeep (in autoComplete or in dataTable).

```
<p:autoComplete ... />
<p:dataTable ...>
    <cc:insertChildren /> <!-- Show columns in dataTable -->
</p:dataTable>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use cc:insertChildren in a view only once per composite component, otherwise a duplicate id exception will be thrown. Unfortunately there is no way that could work :-(.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, that is not going to work and there are no ways to duplicate components declaratively. Closest what you can get is using `<ui:include>` instead.

`columns.xhtml`

```
<ui:composition ...>
    <p:column>#{item.code}</p:column>
    <p:column>#{item.name}</p:column>
</ui:composition>
```

Main view:

```
<util:myCustomComp columnsFile="/columns.xhtml" ... />
```

Composite implementation:

```
<p:autoComplete ...>
    <ui:include src="#{cc.attrs.columnsFile}" />
</p:autoComplete>
<p:dataTable ...>
    <ui:include src="#{cc.attrs.columnsFile}" />
</p:dataTable>
```

*(disclaimer: untested, this may break view scoped beans if partial state saving is turned on)*

Comment: Thanks for help me. But create a new file for each use of this is so hard. Now, I'm using the columns children in dataTable and the toString in autoComplete.